# Trying to find ID is not active at a certain time to keep track of over time

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to find patients `who are active on date 2016-05-01 but not active on date 2016-06-01`, which will be the patient `Z673032`. See the table below

```
pat_id  dm_date
-------------------------------
Z672385 2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
Z672385 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000
Z672444 2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
Z672444 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000
Z672570 2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
Z672570 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000
Z672995 2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
Z672995 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000
Z673032 2016-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

My query:

```
select A.pat_id 
from  A
where 
    A.dm_date = '2016-05-01'
    and A.PAT_ID not in (select B.pat_id 
                         from B
                         where B.dm_date = '2016-06-01')
```

But it returns Null. It should be straightforward but... Any light on this?
I use SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: what is your table name? Are "A" and "B" alias? what are they?

Comment: What is you table name?

Comment: Take a look to BETWEEN statement. Also comparing dates with < > might help

Comment: Are these the only records or are there more records? Is there any record where pat_id is NULL ?

Comment: please provide your column types

Comment: Are you getting syntax error or your get NULL?

Answer (score 1):

You need include the table name before the alias.

Check **[demo fiddle](http://rextester.com/GFGE51993)**

```
select A.pat_id 
from  Table1 A
where 
    A.dm_date = '2016-05-01'
and A.PAT_ID not in (select B.pat_id 
                     from Table1 B
                     where B.dm_date = '2016-06-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the table onto itself like this

```
SELECT a.pat_id 
FROM   a 
       LEFT JOIN b 
              ON a.pat_id = b.pat_id 
WHERE  a.dm_date BETWEEN '2016-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-05-01 23:59:59' 
       AND b.pat_date BETWEEN '2016-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-01 23:59:59'
```

SQL Server can be finicky about how it interprets the dates when comparing to datetime stamps.